# Emails sent from postfix via a Rails app are getting sent to spam in gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postfix-mta

When using 'mail' command to send email to a gmail user, the email goes through fine. When sending an email using a Rails app, the email is sent to the spam folder for the gmail user. Can someone help me think through this?

Comment: Is everything (from address, etc.) the same?  You might also try serverfault

Comment: Could be an array of things: A misconfigured server, blacklisted IP, no proper MX records, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails landing in SPAM can happen due to many reasons:

- Wrong Mail Server setup: Checkout [here](http://madebymany.com/blog/getting-email-around-spam-filters) on how to setup
- Email content: Content of the email can also invite SPAM. Sites like [SpamCheck](http://spamcheck.sitesell.com/) helps to check whether the content of the email is ok.
- As mentioned by @Noli above, using services like [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Critsend](http://critsend.com) etc for sending out emails, chances of landing them in Inbox will be more. You can use them as relay servers from Postfix. But the first two steps are anyway necessary.
- Use [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) if you want to sent emails to many people, for eg: for sending out newsletters, marketing emails etc.

Answer (score 2):

Mail deliverabillty is extraordinarily hard to get right.  You should consider leaving this to the specialists like [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/), and not spend tooooo much development time thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that if this is a new server, you may need to set up Domain Keys to authenticate to Gmail.  This happend to me and I was able to get my mail removed from the spam folder by following these:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DomainKeys

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM